# SqlCommand увеличить максимальное количество параметров

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net, sql-server

SqlCommand не позволяет передать больше 2100 параметров 1 запросом, а также внести больше 1000 строк в базу данных за раз. Можно увеличить это количество до неограниченного? Или есть какие-то ограничения у SQL Server, из-за который нельзя одним запросом передавать много параметров? Хочу сделать функцию для переноса таблицы с данными из одной базы данных в другую. При этом хотелось чтобы функция была способна переносить данные из одного типа бд в другой (например из SQL Server в My SQL).

Comment: Вы пишете коммерческий продукт или у вас потребность во внутренней автоматизации? Если второе -- то сделайте простой инструмент, а не делайте универсальный инструмент за неограниченно долгое время. Выгрузите таблицу как SQL-дамп и загрузите её в другую базу. А гарантией того, что это взлетит будет то, что вы будете формировать дамп в SQL-92, его большинство СУБД поймёт.

Comment: @AK я пытаюсь написать подобие ORM для .net compact 3.5. Одна из задач, которые хочу решить - синхронизировать базу данных устройства на Windows Moblile 5.0 с базой данных на сервере. То есть устройство передает запрос серверной бд какие записи нужно добавить/удалить/отредактировать, сервер обрабатывает запрос и возвращает что базе данных на устройстве нужно добавить/удалить/отредактировать.

Comment: @AK таким образом я пытаюсь решить проблему, что на устройствах база данных устаревает почти сразу после предыдущего обновления, а сервер быстрее будет получать изменения от устройства. Сейчас бд обновляется 1 раз в сутки, это проблема

Comment: В самом SqlCommand ограничений на количество параметров нет, там тупо оболочка над List и никаких лимитов не обнаружено. На каком этапе у вас ошибка возникает? Если на этапе исполнения запроса - это ограничение БД.

Comment: @rdorn на этапе исполнения. Запрос имеет вид " BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERT INTO Entity (Name) VALUES (@Name0), (@Name1) ....... (@NameN) IF (@@error <> 0) ROLLBACK COMMIT;" Используется sql server express

Comment: 2100 - это ограничение SqlServer (см. [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)), для `VALUES`, если память не изменяет, ограничение ещё меньше (кажется 1000).